# My eye won't track to my bone armature

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

When I added an object constraint to my eye mesh, I selected my armature as my target and my bone as the one that I want my eye to track to, but it's not working.

Here's what it looks like:[image]

And every time I move my bone, the eye doesn't track to it. There appears to be a red bar right next to the word Track To in the Constraints Panel, maybe there might be an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the "up" axis is set to *Z* and the "to" axis is set to *Z*. The constraint can't point *Z* up and track it to the armature at the same time. If you want to track to the *Z* axis use a different axis as "up".

Answer (score 0):

red in the constraint stack means that the target is not recognized, maybe you've changed the name of the armature or the bone. Try reassign the right armature and the right bone directly in the costraint menu.

Comment: I checked and I'm pretty sure I assigned the right armature and the right bone to the model, since I looked and selected the armature in the outliner panel, and I also turn the names on as well just to make sure it "was" right.

Comment: Actually never mine, It's not that I have the wrong armature or bone, it's just that for whatever reason the selected axis that they're tracking to is not tracking the bone on the X-axis. sorry should've pointed that out.

Comment: Red doesn't mean the target is not recognized, but that the constraint is disabled. While this is one reason it may be red, it does not mean that it is why it is red every time.